# Ошибка 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, Chrome выдает ошибку следующего содержания.

> Failed to load http://localhost:3000/cars: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Вот запрос с помощью которого обращаюсь к серверу:

```
getData () {
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/cars";
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.onload = function () {
         const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
         if (xhr.status == "200") {
              return response;
         } else {
              console.error(response);
         }
    };
        xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: У вас получается кросс-доменный запрос, возможно вы пытаетесь сделать запрос на другой порт или на другое доменное имя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не ошибка, это ограничение безопасности.

Происходит это из-за того что страница, с которой вы отправляете этот запрос загружена не с этого сервера(порта)

возможно вам достаточно разместить страницу с которой вы отправляете запрос на сервер куда вы отправляете запрос

В противном случае

Ваш веб сервер должен устанавливать заголовок `access-control-allow-origin`

судя по сообщению

> Failed to load http://localhost:3000/cars: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not
>   equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access

у Вас там `null`

для тестирования достаточно поставить туда символ `*` что разрешит кросс доменные запросы

а вообще, Вам сюда [кросс доменные запросы](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Можно:

Есть небольшой трюк с PHP. И этот трюк будет работать не только с Google, но и с любыми сайтами, к которым у вас нет доступа и вы не можете добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Нам нужно создать PHP-файл (например. getContentFromUrl.php) на нашем сервере и сделать обращение к нему.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$ext_url = $_POST['ext_url'];

echo file_get_contents($ext_url);

?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getContentFromUrl.php', // link to your PHP file
    data: {
        // url куда наш сервер будет отправлять запрос, который мы не можем сделать через AJAX
        'ext_url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // теперь мы можем взять любые данные из внешнего url, потому что у нас есть вся страница
        var $h1 = $(data).find('h1').html();

        $('h1').text($h1);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

**Как это работает:**

1. Ваш браузер с помощью JS отправит запрос на ваш сервер
2. Ваш сервер отправит запрос на любой другой сервер и получит ответ
3. Ваш сервер отправит этот ответ в ваш JS файл

И мы можем добавить event типа onClick на кнопку. Надеюсь, это поможет!